# What can change so the app store fails on a network where purchases used to work fine?

Tags: iphone, ipad, applications, ios-appstore

Yesterday, I noticed that when I'm at my office on the wireless network, and I purchase or try to update an app, it doesn't work. Doesn't matter if it is on my iPad or iPhone.  I've never had this problem until this week.

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the 4.3 update, or something with my firewall ( I have complete access to my firewall btw ). I have never had this problem until the other day and the only things that have changed are:

1. Cisco Tech support worked on my firewall. No major config changes though
2. Upgraded all my devices to 4.3

When I'm at home or on 3G everything works as expected. What should I be looking for in my firewall and/or DNS servers to resolve this?

EDIT: I just tried something and got some weird results:
I just tried downloading the free app AppShopper and it *worked* on both iPad and iPhone. If I try to download the Free (but pay to upgrade) app Hunters: Episode One HD on my iPad it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to filter your firewall logs down to requests originating from your computer/your phone's local IP address, and look it it's outgoing requests.

I'm pretty sure all that app download traffic takes place over bog standard HTTPS, 443/tcp.

Ensure all apps have stopped running, open App Store, move over to the Updates category, wait for all traffic (app image requests and the like) to die down, then tap update. The next series of requests should fail, and you should have the reason relevant to your own configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  This is really strange.  I just tried downloading the free app AppShopper and it worked on both iPad and iPhone.  If I try to download the Free (but pay to upgrade) app Hunters: Episode One HD on my iPad it does not work.

Comment: Hmm. Well, you're prompted for your login even if the app is free, so it shouldn't be some weird login bug. Did you download AppShopper first? Or Hunters first?

Comment: I tried Hunters first.. no good.  Then I tried AppShopper and it worked right away.  It's almost as if free apps are allowed and paid apps are not.  I just tried Sniper vs Sniper (paid) and it won't work.  I also changed my dns on my iphone to point to 4.2.2.2 but still no luck.

Comment: It just occurred to me that you could probably shut off WiFi when at work, and use 3G. There are of course ramifications to doing so (ex. not on an "unlimited" plan), but it might be the easiest way around this. At least as far as the App Store is concerned.

Comment: Yes I've done this, and confirmed that it works this way, but some apps that are greater than 10mb (I think) wont' download.  I think i'm on to something though.  Will update.

Comment: I think I fgured something out... I disabled my CSC SSM and the updates started working.  Turned it back on and updates didn't work.  I'm looking into this.  THnaks

Comment: Ok turns out, my firewall has a HTTP scanning module.  It has been on for a year without any problems at all.  Seems that an update to it over the last week has wrecked havoc on some of my network devices using port 80 and 443.  Once I turned it off the iOS devices worked with no problem.  Cisco is aware of the problem and are seeing if it is isolated or something that effects everyone with the device.  Thank you for all your help!